# Xcode align item in center if another item doesn't exists

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alignment, cell

i'm using UICollectionView to display items. My cell contains of ImageView and in the bottom label.
  How to make label in center of cell when ImageView doesn't have image? Lets say:

```
if ("no image in ImageView ") { 
ImageView.setActive = false
"what to do here?"
```

How to center label? Ofcourse i could set constraints value = cellHeight/2
But is there another way to do that? Or could i do that in Xcode editor?

Comment: You can add image view and label in UIStackView. Set stack view distribution to Fill Equally. If there is no image in image view, hide the image view. And your label will be centered.

Comment: nice idea, i'll try that, but is it ok to use UIStackView when my cells are resizable?

Comment: Let me know if it works.

Comment: No it doesn't work, console complains a lot how can't handle constraints

Comment: I'd do two things. (2) Set *both* the image view *and* the label* to be **peers** of the table cell, thus freeing the need to have one dependent of the other - of course, you now need to work with which view if in front. (2) Use the `centerYAnchor` and `centerXAnchor` instead of frame values - which `cellHeight/2` might be. But you really should post more code than you have for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.   **Swift 4.1**

- Add containerViews in your stackView (inside the cell).
- Add your imageViews and labels to the container Views
- Hide one of them and run `layoutIfNeeded()` in the stackView

A working example using a singleView project (use the button to toggle). The same code should work inside cells for `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

You will have to add the `UIStackView` inside the cell and apply `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` anchors

In the example, I use a button to toggle the views, you could use didSet{} in the imageView to hide/show the containerView

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var stackView: UIStackView!
    var topView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        topView = UIView()
        topView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        let bottomView = UIView()
        bottomView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [topView, bottomView])
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        self.view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.centerWithSize(size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 200))
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "hexagon.png")
        topView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.centerWithSize(size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "TEXT"
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
        bottomView.addSubview(label)
        label.centerWithSize(size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        addButton()
    }
    func addButton() {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system) as UIButton
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
        button.setTitle("TOGGLE", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggle), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 100, height: 30)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
    @objc func toggle(sender: UIButton) {
        topView.isHidden = topView.isHidden == true ? false : true
        stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
} 
extension UIView {
   func centerWithSize(size: CGSize) {
       self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
       self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
       self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
       self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But it won't work because of dynamic cell sizes. I have made scattered UICollectionView. Cell size differs by picture size and title string length.